# Can I view remote HTTP directories via something like sshfs?

Tags: linux, mount, http, https

It's possible to mount remote directories via `sshfs`, if you have the correct login credentials to connect via `ssh`.

I've also seen many websites with the 'autoindex' functionality (e.g. [here](https://ht.transparencytoolkit.org/) and [here](http://animorphsfanforum.com/fanart/2064/)).

Since there seems to be a standard for the way these directories are served, is there some way of 'mounting' them as read-only file systems in the same vein as sshfs?

As a follow-up: is it possible to do the same over an encrypted (i.e. HTTPS) connection?